# Not getting results from database - sqlite 3

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to insert a large list of English words into a database, and get the results back. However, when I query the database, it is returning nothing. I have omitted the input of the text file into the database for this example, and have only inserted a single string. However this is not showing up in the query either. Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3

def get_database_connection():
    return sqlite3.connect("myDatabase.db")

def commit():
    connection = get_database_connection()
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

def table_exists(table):
    cursor = get_cursor()
    cursor.execute(''' SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{0}' '''.format(table))
    my_bool = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    return my_bool


def get_cursor():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("myDatabase.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    return cursor


def create_table(table):
    if table_exists(table):
        return
    cursor = get_cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE {0}(
                        word text
                        )""".format(table))

def insert_english_words():
    #english_words = "english.txt"
    #words = process_words(english_words)
    table = "english"
    create_table(table)
    cursor = get_cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO english VALUES ('HELLO')")
    #for word in words:
        #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO english VALUES ('{0}')".format(word))
    commit()

def get_data():
    cursor = get_cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM english")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)


def run():
    get_database_connection()
    insert_english_words()
    get_data()
    print("Done")


run()
```

Comment: You have to commit after creation of table.

Comment: The problem is that you are constantly creating new db connections, and you are using different ones for operations where you should use the same one. You should simplify your code, all these little functions that call each other and overlap a bit don't help to see clearly what happens. Also, lots of them don't even have parameters: how could they act upon your data? (see `commit` for example)

Comment: I think @ThierryLathuille brings up a very good point. Forget solving this specific issue, focus on fixing the design of your program. He mentioned that many of your functions lack parameters, I will add that not only do they take no parameters and return no values, they’re only ever used once. Why even create functions in the first place, if they seemingly fulfill none of the goals and offer none of the benefits of functions?

Comment: As an aside, don’t use “empty” `return`s. Either return something, or don’t write a return statement at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to commit after creation of table.
Maintain one single connection object across your script lifecycle. You are creating a new connection every single time.